# (sql) Сортировка элементов

Tags: sql, сортировка

Приветствую Нужна помощь! Создаю и заполняю таблицу данными запросами. Заранее Спасибо!!

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
      id INT,
      ParentId INT,
      Name VARCHAR(256)
    );

INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (1, 0, 'debian');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (2, 1, 'ubuntu');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (3, 2, 'kubuntu');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (4, 2, 'lubuntu');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (5, 2, 'linux mint');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (6, 0, 'slackware');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (7, 6, 'slax');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (8, 7, 'wolvix');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (9, 7, 'slampp');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (10, 7, 'dnalinux');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (11, 6, 'suse');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (12, 11, 'linkat');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (13, 11, 'opensuse');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (14, 0, 'redhate');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (15, 14, 'fedora core');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (16, 15, 'sailfish os');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (17, 15, 'fedora');
```

Вывод мне нужен в таком виде:

```
slackware
   slax
      slampp
      dnalinux
   suse
      linkat
redhat
   fedora core
      sailfish os
      fedora
```

Пытаюсь сделать запросом :

```
SELECT lpad(' ', 3*level)||name as TreeTable
FROM test_table
WHERE name LIKE '%a%'
START WITH ParentID = 0
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = ParentID
ORDER SIBLINGS BY ParentId;
```

Получается вывод:

```
debian
   slackware
      slax
         slampp
         dnalinux
         linkat
   redhate
      fedora core
         sailfish os
         fedora
```

Comment: Как то так http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c58d14/7 Но мне не нравится, оно может давать пустые ветки дерева, в которых нет ни одного листа. Хотя вы не сказали что like должен работать только для листьев. Что если буква 'a' есть в названии какого то промежуточного уровня, но у него самого нет подчиненных узлов с буквой 'a' ? Так что опишите точно, каковы критерии показа элементов, на что должен действовать тот like

Comment: Если в группе нет элементов, то не выводить эту группу.

значение фильтра: «а». В результате должны получить список. должно работать для любого наполнения таблицы и любого фильтра

Comment: Какой список ? Если бы в slax были бы элементы, но все без буквы 'a', то сам slax надо было бы показывать ?

Comment: нет не нужно показывать :)

Comment: И никакого признака нет, что это конечный элемент, который подвержен поиску ?  Т.е. как определять к каким записям применять like, по отсутствию дочерних элементов ?

Comment: ну получается что если в дочерних элементах есть буква, то выводить и родителя  и всех детей с этой буквой даже если у родителя нет ее

Comment: Это понятно, но вы сказали, что если бы в дочерних элементах slax не было бы 'a', то сам slax то же выводить не надо (не смотря на то, что в нем самом буква 'a' есть). Так чем таким отличается slax, от его дочерних элементов, что на него поиск не распространяется ?

Comment: ну я так понимаю что только по третьему уровню поиск должен идти и если в третьем уровне есть элементы с буквой то выводить всю ветвь. Возможно ли такой запрос сделать?

Comment: выходит что не распространяется

Comment: так ... почему именно 3й уровень ? я подозреваю, что количество уровней не ограничено. И тогда условие все таки: "найти такие элементы у которых нет дочерних и при этом в названии присутствует 'a', после чего вывести их со всеми родителями". И плохо что у них нет другого признака, что они последние. И да, конечно запрос можно сделать, просто отбор надо начать с этих самых дочерних. Я после работы подумаю над этим, пока времени нет

Comment: И еще версия оркла важна, может потребоваться sys_connect_by_path ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT lpad(' ', 3*level)||name as TreeTable
  FROM (
    SELECT distinct *
      FROM test_table t
     START WITH name LIKE '%a%'
       and not exists(select 1 from test_table x where x.parentId = t.id)
   CONNECT BY id = PRIOR ParentID
  ) x
   START WITH ParentID = 0
 CONNECT BY PRIOR id = ParentID
 ORDER SIBLINGS BY ParentId;
```

Внутренний подзапрос находит все листья дерева, удовлетворяющие условию и их родителей. Внешний запрос строит из них дерево, начиная с корневого элемента. Если требуется искать так же промежуточные элементы, удовлетворяющие условию like, то надо убрать проверку not exists.

Пример на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c58d14/9)

Comment: спасибо огромное!!